# Adding a ground bar to a Cutler-Hammer main panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am adding an EV charging (240V) to my main panel (200A). After doing all the work, I realized that I don't have enough space on my neutral / ground bar. Initially I thought I would adjust some wires, but I don't have enough space.

My next option is to add a ground bar and since I haven't done this before I have few questions.

1. Can I add anther small bar with the current hole I have open in the current bar? (Pic #1) If so, what bar would fit?
2. I do see I have some knobs in the panel that I think are for mounting new ground bar (Pic #2). I measured and the distance b/w them is 6cm. I am not sure what Ground bar would fit? Do I need to knock the holes completely out inorder to connect the new bar?
3. If I do install a new bar, can I connect it by 6 gauge wire to the old bus?
4. If I do install a new bar can I connect both the neutral and the ground of the new 240v outlet to it?

Pic1

[image]

Pic2

[image]

Pic3

[image]

Comment: First: you also need somewhere to land the neutral wire for the now code-required GFCI if you're going to use an outlet instead of hard wiring. Second: hard wiring will let you skip the neutral and might mean you have enough room on the bar.

Comment: Right now all the neutral and wires are going to the same bus. Can't I do the same? I can move few grounds to the new bar to make some room for the nuetral. What do you mean by hard wiring? I am plug-in to nema 14-50.

Comment: @Yuvi -- as in, having the charger wired directly to a box on the wall instead of wired to a plug that then plugs into a receptacle

Comment: I see. I think that not applicable in my situation though...

Comment: @Yuvi if you are installing a 240V socket anywhere anyone would charge an EV (e.g. not a bedroom), you must provide a GFCI breaker to protect the SOCKET.   If you don't want to pay $200 for a GFCI, then get a wall unit EVSE and hardwire it.  If you suffer under the belief that you MUST use the provided charger, that is false - all EV chargers are intercompatible - Even Tesla's with an adapter entirely made of brass and plastic (no active electronics).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll buy the GFCI  as I understand this is the new code. However, my issue remains. With the current wiring on the current bus, I am not sure I have another spot for even 1 6 gauge wire.

Comment: @Yuvi -- the GFCI is completely unnecessary if you don't have the socket in the way, even under the latest Codes

Comment: Is this a split bus panel? If so, you would want to have the breaker for the EV charging circuit above in parallel with the "main" breaker, right? Can a two pole GFCI breaker be installed hot? (There is no local shutoff in the top section of a split bus panel.)

Answer (score 5):

### Edit: Time for a new way to charge your Teslas

Now that I have the full picture, you have a Tesla and you're charging a second one, and you were using a 14-50 RV socket and you want to use another one for simultaneous charging of two vehicles.  *You cannot do that with this panel.  It is not in any way safe. Remember what I said below about haphazardly adding loads to a Rule of Six panel without a Load Calculation?  Adding 100A of load is Right Out.*

And you're making [the mistake that Technology Connections warns about here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s). This is bonkers overkill, especially for Teslas.  Upside: your cars finish nightly charging by 1 AM, downside: your panel melts and you have an emergency $5000 panel replacement.

That said, I gather you don't want to pay for a service upgrade.

Alright. But we need to graduate out of using the travel units for daily charging.  It's time to get two [Tesla Wall Connector 3.0's](https://shop.tesla.com/product/wall-connector) and use [Power Sharing](https://www.tesla.com/en_gb/support/charging/wall-connector/power-sharing).

Had you not already run the circuit for the second socket, I would have said to simply fork the socket to both Wall Connectors and call it a day. You can still do that if you want to, or just use the second circuit you have run.

Either way, commission the Wall Connectors as a "Power Sharing" pair. Set them to each max out at 50A but share a maximum pull of 50A.  That should work alright with your other breakers, since now the two Teslas together are counting as one 50A breaker.   That'll put you at 210A simply by sum of breakers - 60A main, 50A induction cooktop + 20A oven, 30A dryer, and 50A for both Tesla stations together thanks to Power Sharing.

I'm OK with that being at 210A, because of NEC 220.55 -- ranges and ovens actually calculate to considerably less than their nameplate, because they run at a duty cycle.

### Accessory ground bars

Read the panel labeling under the "Accessories" section, and you will see several model numbers of ground bar listed.  Stop by the friendly neighborhood Eaton dealer and say "I'd line *n* of model X please" and they'll disappear into the back and come back a minute later with them.

One of the figures in the model number will reflect the number of usable screws on the bar. For exact configuration, check [the catalog](https://www.eaton.com/ecm/groups/public/@pub/@electrical/documents/content/vol01_tab01.pdf) page 27.  You seem to have found one of the sites they are designed to mount to. There are several.

### Let's talk provisioning

This is a Cutler Hammer "Rule of Six" aka "Split-Bus" panel.  If you don't have an outside main breaker at the meter, this is a dangerous old type, because you do not have one main breaker: you have six.  The breaker labeled "Main" powers the "Lighting Area", the last 7 rows of breakers. It should be labeled "Lighting" because in fact all six are main breakers, and must be identified clearly.

This panel type harkens back to when breakers over 60A were prohibitively expensive, yet they wanted to provide 100-200A services to homes. The workaround was to put up to six large loads in a totally unfused section, where all six breakers are The Main Breakers.

This panel is dangerous because the breakers can sum to more than the service capacity, and **nothing prevents the panel from being overloaded** except the NEC 220.82 Load Calculation.  That's fine the day the house is built and signed off... the problems come later when people add huge loads, *like gosh, a 50A EV station - the harshest load a house will ever handle.*

I don't know your service size - if the wire is copper it's 200A, if it's aluminum it might be 150A - look for wire size markings and compare to Table 310.12 (which sizes *services*). 4/0 wire is 200A in that table.

Now if the sum of the top 6 breakers are <= your service size, you are fine. Rule of Six is no concern then.  I also see an open 2-pole breaker in your "Lighting Area" and if that's the one you plan to use, that will help too.

Otherwise, you have two options, and neither one is fun. (well the second one is very fun). First, you can grind through a NEC 220.82 Load Calculation, and [Sacramento is kind enough to provide an excellent worksheet here](https://www.cityofsacramento.org/-/media/Corporate/Files/CDD/Building/Forms/CDD-0213_Electrical-Load-Calculation-Worksheet.pdf?la=en). Note that most loads get a 40% fold-down - HVAC and EV charging do not. Or Second, you can completely ignore the Load Calc by using EVEMS aka Load Management - put clamp meters on your service wires, and setup the EVSE ("charger") to automatically adjust EV charge rate so EV charging never exceeds 80% of service capacity.  This is neat because there is no speed limit.  If you have 200A service you could literally get a 40kW DC fast charger!

### Let's talk EV charging

First, welcome to EVs. Unfortunately every novice EVer gets handed a "travel unit" and a HUGE pack of misconceptions about how home charging needs to be done, and countless dollars are wasted.   Oddly, some EVers scrimp and pinch every penny, while others don't even blink if told an $8000 service upgrade is needed. (It's NOT.)

I know you feel locked into your plan, but you'll want to unlock I think.

To start out, that "travel charger" is [for exactly this here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_naDg-guomA&t=676s). (plan: 11:15-13:15, execution 26:14.)  Note the part at 28:56 where the car has gone from 15% to 98% in 8 hours - that's important for travel like Grey is doing, but bonkers overkill for home, where you only need to replace daily usage.

Technology Connections has [a lovely primer video on home charging here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w).

Novices like sockets because the "travel units" feel cheaper.  Not so much.  First, the cheap NEMA 14-50 sockets melt - a lot.  We have weekly reports of melted sockets on various forums. Most of them are made for ranges, which are plugged in once every 20 years.  You need the better "RV Park grade" Hubbell/Bryant sockets, typically $80.    And second, since 2017, Code has required GFCI protection for 240V sockets, particularly those used for EV charging.  And now you're looking at a $140++ breaker.  See why we don't like sockets?  You don't need a GFCI breaker for a hardwired unit, it *is* a GFCI.

Also, using the travel unit for daily charging is going to get old.  You'll be happier with a conveniently placed wall unit, and then the travel unit can live in the trunk for opportunity charging on the road. And wall units are not heinously expensive anymore. At $400 you're a player, and the EVEMS/Load Management stuff I mentioned adds only a few hundred more.

### A solution

Frankly, given the Gordian Knot of the provisioning problems I see in this panel, that would be my first choice here. Bypass the Load Calc by using the "CT clamps on the service wires" trick. Typical setups are (if you prefer a data cable connection that can't fail) the Wallbox Pulsar Plus($500) + power meter ($300)...  or (if you can deliver solid WiFi to both panel and garage; if you can't it won't charge) the Emporia Load Management bundle ($600) which includes a nice home energy monitor to boot.

Now let's talk about wire. That looks to me like 6 AWG MC cable. Not UF or NM, which means, it's 65A wire.   So you can stretch the extra 10 amps available from a hardwired unit to 60A breaker / 48A charge, if you aren't listening to Alec from the video lol.  Either the Emporia or the faster, non-CostCo Wallbox can do that.

Being able to do that - when literally every electrician you ask would tell you that you need a service upgrade - is pretty good, if you ask me.

Comment: Harper, this is a great answer. One thing: are you sure that isn't THHN in FMC? It wouldn't change the 65A ampacity anyway.

Comment: Thanks Harper for this detailed response!!

Regarding this "sum of the top 6 breakers are <= your service size", are you referring to the actual max amp each breaker will consume? I ask because I already have 50amp breaker for a Nema 14-50 to charge Tesla (I now own 2). They will charge at 32amp max. So, so should I count it as 50amp or 32amp?

Comment: Currently the set up for the 6 is: 60a for main, 50a cooktop induction, 50a 14-50 for tesla charging, 30a dryer, 20a for an oven and one extra that was for 20a AC. I was thinking to lower the 20a AC (this is the disconnected breaker you see in the picture under main currently) to be under the "main" as it has less chance to consume too much amp under my main and add the 50a breaker for the new outlet for another Tesla under the "6".

Comment: So if I count each breaker as the actual breaker label, then with the AC breaker then the total is 210, but if I count per Max amp, it will be less than 200a. If I'll install Tesla charger it will be 230. What will be the better option?

Comment: @Yuvi holy smokes, I had no idea you already had a Tesla. That changes everything. You should be using Power Sharing for the second station. Running two independent 50A circuits on a split bus panel just does not work. See edit.

Comment: Thanks Harper. Yeah, I was starting to look at that option as well thanks to your answer. Do you think I can do a power share while upgrading the current 50a breaker to 60a? (Currently I am using southwire e51583 awg 6 wires)

Comment: With the upgrade to 60a, I can move the 20amp AC breaker under the main (as this is the only 240v under the main)

Comment: Harper, one more question. Can I do the fork in the main control panel? This way I just have to change the sockets to the Tesla wall chargers.

Comment: @Yuvi Yeah, #6 THWN is good to 65A.  Yes, you can do the split in the main panel. Actually for simplicity of wiring, they can be on 2 different 60A breakers as long as you set the Power Sharing limit to 48A actual, they will count in th Load Calc as 60A.